# How to extract news article from html links of anckor tags

Tags: javascript, python, html, scrapy, summarization

someone who can help me on how to extract the news text available in the following tags.

```html
<a href="tigrinya/news-50612332.html" class="faux-block-link__overlay-link" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"> ሕሉፍ ወልፊ ሞባይል፡ ንመንእሰያት ራዕዲ ከምዝፈጥረሎም ተገሊጹ</a>" and "
<a href="tigrinya/news-50605565.html" class="title-link">
  <h3 class="title-link__title">
    <span class="title-link__title-text">ሃገራዊ ቦርድ መረጻ ኢትዮጵያ ንብልጽግና ፓርቲ ኣይመዝገብኩዎን ኢሉ</span>
  </h3>
</a>
```

Comment: can you show me your scrapy code

Answer (score 0):

**use python BeautifulSoup library to parse HTML data**

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """ ሕሉፍ ወልፊ ሞባይል፡ ንመንእሰያት ራዕዲ ከምዝፈጥረሎም ተገሊጹ" and "

  
    ሃገራዊ ቦርድ መረጻ ኢትዮጵያ ንብልጽግና ፓርቲ ኣይመዝገብኩዎን ኢሉ
  
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

print(soup.find('span', {'class': 'title-link__title-text'}).text)

Comment: Thanks, for timely answer may question. just to make clear, what i want is, to extract the actual news paragraph. because it only give me the tile under the tag spam only.

Comment: the code i used is "html = urllib.request.urlopen('file:///G:/My%20Web%20Sites/BBC%20Tigrigna/www.bbc.com/tigrinya.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
data = soup.findAll(text=True)",